# how to sort json string?

Tags: php, json

I want to parse the JSON string below into an associative array, sort it by the 'age' field and output the sorted array as an HTML table:

```
<?
$json='[{"name": "jesse","age": 25},{"name": "jason","age": 29},{"name": "johnson","age": 24}]';

?>
```

Should I use some sort of json_decode to print the individual values and use an existing sorting function in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only way (I know of) is to use:

```
$array = json_decode( $json);
$array = array_map( $array, 'objectToArray');

// Or rather:
$array = json_decode( $json, true);

// And sort
sort( $array);
```

Php offers [many array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) functions, just browse manual. I also borrowed `objectToArray` from [this page](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/).

I guess you will want to sort by age (or name), you should probably use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function cmp( $a, $b){
  if( !isset( $a['age']) && !isset( $b['age'])){
    return 0;
  }

  if( !isset( $a['age'])){
    return -1;
  }

  if( !isset( $b['age'])){
    return 1;
  }

  if( $a['age'] == $b['age']){
    return 0;
  }

  return (($a['age'] > $b['age']) ? 1 : -1);
}

usort( $array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `json_decode` the string which will give you a php array of associate arrays.  From there you can use php 's built in sort to sort on the key you want.