# Sort JSON by ID

Tags: php, json, sorting

I have following JSON file:

```
[{
    "id": 9,
    "title": "Birthday",
    "description": "Debut Party",
    "start": "2017-07-25T15:01",
    "end": "2017-08-03T00:01",
    "url": "https:\/\/bd.com"
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Anniversary",
    "description": "First Ann",
    "start": "2017-06-28T15:00",
    "end": "2017-07-08T02:58",
    "url": "https:\/\/anniversary.com\/"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Anniversary",
    "description": "First Ann",
    "start": "2017-06-28T15:00",
    "end": "2017-07-08T02:58",
    "url": "https:\/\/anniversary.com\/"
}]
```

I want them to be sorted by `id` like `5,9,11` using PHP. How Can I do that?

Comment: Did you try the search function?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196925/how-to-sort-json-string

Comment: You want to send sorted json to client side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196925/how-to-sort-json-string)

Comment: Yes that json issaves in data.json and I am displaying it in a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decode the JSON

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
```

and then use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort by id or something else.

```
function sortById($a, $b) {
    return $b->id - $a->id;
}
usort($array,"sortById");
```

Comment: how to use usort by id?

Comment: hi! its warning
 usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\event-cms\index.php on line 80

Comment: Yes Yamen Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

use this query in you php file.
example :

```
function getPosts()
{
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", DatabaseManager::DATABASE_NAME);
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 'id' desc;";
    $result = $connection->query($sqlQuery);
    $postsArray = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++) {
            $postsArray[$i] = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($postsArray);
}
```

Comment: I am using json